# CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED ERROR by call cudnnRNNForwardTrainingEx function

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, cudnn

I want to use cudnnRNNForwardTrainingEx for variable sequence length, but when I set variable sequences length by call

```
cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor(_x_data_desc
, _cudnn_data_type
, CUDNN_RNN_DATA_LAYOUT_SEQ_MAJOR_UNPACKED//curent fix time major
, step
, batch
, _input_size
, seq_len
, (void *)&fill_value //
);
cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor(_y_data_desc
, _cudnn_data_type
, CUDNN_RNN_DATA_LAYOUT_SEQ_MAJOR_UNPACKED//curent fix time major
, step
, batch
, _hidden_size * _dir_count
, seq_len
, (void *)&fill_value //, NULL
);
```

I got error CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED , But only set seq_len all equals step, it run correct, What's problem ?

Env Detail :

- Tesla T4
- NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01 Driver Version: 440.33.01
- CUDA Version: 10.2
- Cudnn v7.6.5

Some Sample code details:

```
auto rnn_direction_mode = _bi_direction ?
CUDNN_BIDIRECTIONAL : CUDNN_UNIDIRECTIONAL;

CudnnRunCheckRet(cudnnDropoutGetStatesSize(_handle, &_dropout_state_size));
CudaRunCheckRet(cudaMalloc(&_dropout_state_ptr, _dropout_state_size));
CudnnRunCheckRet(cudnnSetDropoutDescriptor(_dropout_desc, _handle, 0.0f
, _dropout_state_ptr, _dropout_state_size, 0));
CudnnRunCheckRet(cudnnSetRNNDescriptor_v6(_handle
, _rnn_desc
, _hidden_size, _stack_layer_num
, _dropout_desc, _rnn_input_mode
, rnn_direction_mode, _cudnn_rnn_mode
, CUDNN_RNN_ALGO_STANDARD
, _cudnn_data_type));
CudnnRunCheckRet(
cudnnSetRNNMatrixMathType(_rnn_desc, CUDNN_TENSOR_OP_MATH));
float fill_value = 0;
CudnnRunCheckRet(
cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor(_x_data_desc
, _cudnn_data_type
, CUDNN_RNN_DATA_LAYOUT_SEQ_MAJOR_UNPACKED//curent fix time major
, step
, batch
, _input_size
, seq_len
, (void *)&fill_value //, NULL
));
CudnnRunCheckRet(
cudnnSetRNNDataDescriptor(_y_data_desc
, _cudnn_data_type
, CUDNN_RNN_DATA_LAYOUT_SEQ_MAJOR_UNPACKED//curent fix time major
, step
, batch
, _hidden_size * _dir_count
, seq_len
, (void *)&fill_value //, NULL
));

_x0_desc.set3dDesc(_cudnn_data_type, batch, _input_size, 1);
_y0_desc.set3dDesc(_cudnn_data_type, batch, _hidden_size * _dir_count, 1);
_state_size = 2 * _dir_count * _stack_layer_num * batch * _hidden_size ;
_ht_desc.set3dDesc(_cudnn_data_type, _stack_layer_num * _dir_count, batch, _hidden_size);
_ct_desc.set3dDesc(_cudnn_data_type, _stack_layer_num * _dir_count, batch, _hidden_size);
CudnnRunCheckRet(
cudnnRNNForwardTrainingEx(
_handle
, _rnn_desc
, _x_data_desc, gx->void_ptr()
, _ht_desc, init_ht
, _ct_desc, init_ct
, _par_desc, gw->void_ptr()
, _y_data_desc, gy->void_ptr()
, _ht_desc, out_ht
, _ct_desc, out_ct
, nullptr, nullptr
, nullptr, nullptr
, nullptr, nullptr
, nullptr, nullptr
, g_work->void_ptr(), _work_size
, g_reser->void_ptr(), _reserver_size
));
```

Does anyone can tell me what's the problem ? Thanks